# Git post-receive not working on non-bare repo

Tags: git, windows-7, msysgit, git-post-receive

I'm trying to get a simple Git post-receive hook to work, but it doesn't seem to be running.

All I have in it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout -f master
```

Note that this is a non-bare repository (I've set denyCurrentBranch = ignore) so that I can push to it.

However, when I push to it, it doesn't seem to run the `git checkout -f` command. Running the same command then in the command line does as expected.

Note that this is a simple test case just using local repositories on my C drive.

I've managed to get a post-receive hook working by having a bare repo and putting `git push` in it. My intention is to have a bare "shared" repo which in the post-receive, then automatically pushes to the non-bare "website" repo (which then needs to automatically do a `git checkout -f`).

Any ideas why this isn't working for the non-bare repo? Or any tips on how to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was because the current working directory in the non-bare repo is the `.git` directory.

So while I could just do this in the bare repo (because the git meta data folder is the same folder as the repo root) ...

```
#!/bin/sh
git do something
```

In a non-bare repo, I have to do this ...

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=.. git do something
```

Comment: (git noob here, I only know sourctree). I put that exactly the same code for my post-receive and still not working. I tried to run git checkout -f while inside project/.git/hooks and there is an error, then I changed my worling dir into project/ then ran the same command and it worked right.

Comment: I have a similar problem because when pushing from the local machine to the remote server , hook does not work (nothing happens, hook not triggered). But I don't understand your solution. Where did you put this code? On remote `post-receive`? Can you show a full example? I used --work-tree and --git-dir but not working